# How to convert Japanese Kana to IPA phonetics?

Tags: phonetics

I'm a Chinese student interested in Japanese language processing. As far as I know, ususally Japanese Kana can be represented in Romaji letters. But I wonder how can I convert Kana into IPA phonetics? Is there any mapping?

Comment: By IPA, do you mean `[tɕɯ]` and so on? Does [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think that's exacly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology for more details. E.g. ん ("Moraic nasal") has different realizations depending on preceding and following phones.

Comment: kana and sound is not always 1-1. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97854/45489

Answer (score 3):

The IPA notation for each hiragana is [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana).

However, the table only shows how the character is typically pronounced in isolation. As pointed out in the comments section, please be aware that some characters may be pronounced differently depending on the context. This is known as [**allophones**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9333/5010). Every language has allophones, but native speakers are usually unaware of them. Notable examples in Japanese include:

- [[ɴ] vs [m] vs [n] vs [ŋ] for ん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15589/5010)
- [[g] vs [ng] for が/ぎ/ぐ/げ/ご](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26227/5010) (bidakuon)
- [[dz] v [z] for ざ/じ/ず/ぜ/ぞ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18094/5010)

Comment: Thanks for your answer！It's really helpful!

Comment: Also, at the phonemic level, う usually becomes /o/ (or lengthening, depending on your analysis) after /o/, and similarly い becomes /e/ after /e/ in many dialects.